# 'echo' does not print unicode on startup

Tags: linux, arch-linux, unicode

I'm running a quite fresh installation of Arch and the startup is set up like this (simplified):

1. `.zprofile`-> `exec startx` # only `startx` is called here
2. `.xinit` -> `exec bspwm` # xinit is the default from `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` with the `exec` line added at the end
3. `.bspwmrc` -> `echo -e '\uf073' > ~/log.txt`

After startup if I check the contents of `~/log.txt` I see `\uF073` (**note: capital F**). If I run the same echo command after startup in either `sh`, `bash`, `zsh` it prints the correct unicode character.

Rebuilding the font cache doesn't help.

I assumed the fonts are not ready that early and I added a sleep before and it made no difference.

EDIT (1): running the same echo from a another tty without X renders the same `\uF073` meaning the echo from my `.bspwmrc` is executed too early. But what would be a good way to fix this? The documentations says to start `bspwm` in `xinitrc`

The process is running under my user if that matters in any way.

I'm a bit stumped right now and I would appreciate some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Arch-specific(?) solution

During startup your `LANG` is probably `C` but afterwards (e.g. in `zsh`) it is different (e.g. `en_US.UTF-8`). The behavior of `echo` depends on it. Check the [Arch docs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/locale), most likely you don't have a system locale set in `/etc/locale.conf` and neither a user locale in your `~/.config/locale.conf`; still something adds it later after startup. Explicitly add the desired locale to your `~/.config/locale.conf`. This should make things work.

Below are the explanation and some ideas for the general case.

---

#### General solution

This is because at the moment the troublesome `echo` runs, your locale setting does not support Unicode.

In a shell where `echo -e '\uf073'` works, compare these two:

```
echo -e '\uf073'           # should work
LANG=C echo -e '\uf073'    # expect \uF073
```

The least aggressive fix is to run `echo` inside `.bspwmrc` with any locale that supports Unicode. Like this:

```
LANG=C.UTF-8 echo -e '\uf073' > ~/log.txt
```

A more aggressive way is to declare (and export) `LANG` (and maybe `LC_*` variables) earlier in the script to affect everything after. I don't use any software associated with `.bspwmrc`, so I cannot tell you what the overall impact will be. A good idea may be to set the variable for a subshell only:

```
some_command    # this will not be affected
( export LANG=C.UTF-8
  echo …
  echo …
  whatever      # all this will be affected
)
other_command   # this will not be affected
# And the shell sourcing .bspwmrc (if this is what happens) will not be affected.
```

Notes:

- Check your current locale with `locale`. In `.bspwmrc` you may want to use exactly the one you normally use.
- To list all locales installed in your system, invoke `locale -a`.
- In general shells have their own `echo` builtins, there is also a standalone `echo` executable (e.g. `/bin/echo`). Each `echo` may or may not support `\u`. From the fact `f` was capitalized, I conclude the interpreter that reads your `.bspwmrc` invokes `echo` which understands `\u`, locale is the only problem. If it was not the case, these are few possible workarounds:

  - Explicitly invoke a shell whose `echo` builtin supports `\u`:

    ```
    bash -c 'LANG=C.UTF-8 echo -e "\uf073"'
    ```
  - Use `printf` with `\u`:

    ```
    LANG=C.UTF-8 printf '\uf073\n'
    ```

    Note `printf` may or may not be a builtin. Like `echo` it may or *may not* support `\u`.
  - Use `printf` without `\u`:

    ```
    printf '\xef\x81\xb3\n'
    ```

    This sequence of bytes was taken from what `echo -e '\uf073' | xxd` shows in my Kubuntu. Still any `printf` may or *may not* support `\x`. Note this approach does not depends on locale.

  If you are limited to a POSIX shell and POSIX tools (I mean POSIX only, without extensions), printing Unicode characters [may not be easy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27652458/10765659).

Comment: Note that – unfortunately – `C.UTF-8` still only exists as a distro-specific patch, and you will not be able to use it on Arch yet.

Comment: @user1686 Feel free to improve this *community wiki* answer then.

Comment: `oh-my-zsh` was the one changing the locale from `C` to `en_US.UTF-8`. I was using the default config and it included setting `LANG` and `LC_ALL`.